# Generar objetos con bucle "for" con información ya introducida por teclado

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando resolver este problema de la cual no consigo ver la luz xD.
Quiero crear un programa que introduzcas una serie de datos por teclado y se guarde en un array de objetos con un tamaño fijado por teclado.
En la parte del Main  "Empleado[i] = new Empleado(nombre, apellido, edad, salario)" no puedo instanciar dentro del bucle "for", espero me puedan dar pistas,

muchas gracias

```
using System;


namespace SoloPracticas

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String nombre = "";
            String apellido = "";
            int edad = 0;
            float salario = 0f;
            int numEmpl = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Cuantos empleados va a introducir en el sistema?");
            numEmpl = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Empleado[] misEmpleados = new Empleado[numEmpl];

            for (int i = 0; i < numEmpl; i++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Introduce el nombre del empleado");
                nombre = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Introduce los apellidos del empleado");
                apellido = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Introduce la edad del empleado");
                edad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Introduce el salario del empleado");
                salario = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Empleado[i] = new Empleado(nombre, apellido, edad, salario);
            }
        }
    }

    class Empleado
    {
        private String nombre = "";
        private String apellido = "";
        private int edad = 0;
        private float salario = 0f;
        private static int id = 0;
        public int MyId = 0;
        
        public Empleado(String nombre, String apellido, int edad, float salario)
        {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.edad = edad;
            this.salario = salario;
            MyId = id++;
        }

        public String getNombre()
        {
            return nombre;
        }

        public int getEdad()
        {
            return edad;
        }

        public float getSalario()
        {
            return salario;
        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return MyId;

        }   
    }

    class Currito : Empleado
    {

        public Currito(String nombre, String apellido, int edad, float salario): base(nombre, apellido, edad, salario)
        {
            
            
        }
        
    }

    class Jefe : Empleado
    {
        public Jefe(String nombre, String apellido, int edad, float salario): base(nombre, apellido, edad, salario)
        {
            
        }
        
    }
    }
```

Comment: Y como sabes que no te funciona? donde llamas al array para ver la info?

Comment: No me compila el programa, directamente el Rider me subraya "Empleado [i]" en rojo. Aún no hice el for para visualizar los resultados por esto mismo

Comment: Debes poner misEmpleados[i], que es como se llama tu variable

Comment: Omg!!! No me puedo creer que haya cometido ese error . Muchas gracias y perdona por cometer dicho crimen jaja.

Answer (score 1):

Debes utilizar `misEmpleados[i]` para poder instanciarlo.

Saludos,

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ha sido un error muy grave, no se como no he podido verlo jaja